# Asp.net mvc 4 ado.net o lambda?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

Estimados, recien empiezo en programacion asp.net mvc 4 y la verdad que me siento algo perdido.

Yo vengo de trabajar en Windows Forms y ASP.Net N capas, la cual utilizaba ADO.Net y se me hacía más fácil crear mis *Stored Procedures* en SQL y enlazarlo a ASP.Net. Ahora que estoy tratando de utilizar Razor y lambda lo encuentro mas fácil en alguna cosas y más difíciles en otras como por ejemplo hacer un `inner join` de lambda.

¿Cómo pasar este `inner join` a expresión lambda?

```
SELECT fechaEmision
    ,nombreArea
    ,nombreTipoSolicitud
FROM Solicitudes
INNER JOIN TipoSolicitudes ON TipoSolicitudes.TipoSolicitudesID = Solicitudes.TipoSolicitudesID
INNER JOIN Condiciones ON Condiciones.CondicionesID = Solicitudes.CondicionesID
INNER JOIN Areas ON Areas.AreasID = TipoSolicitudes.AreasID
```

Comment: He quitado la parte final de tu pregunta debido a que las preguntas basadas en opiniones no son parte de la temática del sitio. Si deseas saber más detalles acerca del funcionamiento del sitio, sugiero que tomes el [tour] así como también [ask].

Comment: De igual forma veo que has realizado varias preguntas y no has aceptado ninguna. Si alguna de ellas te ha sido de ayuda, dale clic en `✓` y que servirá de referencia a otros usuarios que revisan el sitio día con día. Así como también votar positivo aquellas que te hayan ayudado a encontrar soluciones a tus problemas

Comment: Tranquilamente puedes "reciclar" tus conocimientos con ADO.net, los SP para la capa de datos, recuerda que MVC es la capa de presentación, con tal que hagas buen uso de los Models y ViewModels, enlazarlos a tu capa de negocios debería ser simple. Por otro lado, esta pregunta está basada en opiniones por lo que no te sorprenda si termina cerrada. Saludos :D

Answer (score 1):

Se a lo que te refieres, por un tiempo sufrí la transición. Solo será cuestión de acostumbrarte, y referente a tu pregunta.

Por la naturaleza te recomiendo que inicies con LINQ ya que el lenguaje que trabaja es casi exacto al de SQL.

```
var nuevaSolicitudes = from Solicitudes in sol
                     join TipoSolicitudes in tipo on tipo.TipoSolicitudesID equals sol.TipoSolicitudesID 
                     join Condiciones in con on con.CondicionesID equals sol.CondicionesID 
                     join Areas in area on areas.CondicionesID equals sol.AreasID 
                     select sol.fechaEmision, sol.nombreArea, sol.nombreTipoSolicitud;
```

[Ejemplo de Inner Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql)